# About using sshfs as multi-user file system (different hosts) and potential problems

Tags: ssh, encryption, mount

I have a large online storage for backups which I mainly access through sshfs. Since I am using encfs for encryption (I know about the security concerns but even weak encryption is better than no encryption at all) I need the remote system to be mounted.

The problem is that I have multiple clients (two at least) who should have access to the (encrypted) files. I know that encfs doesn't really care if it's mounted simultaniously on different machines (at least I think so) but sshfs does. I read about it being a single-user filesystem and that you should avoid mounting the same share twice through sshfs.

However, it seems to work fine but I don't want to risk the integrity of my backups. So what could happen if the same directory is mounted through sshfs simultaniously on different machines? How are my files endangered? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: `sshfs` does not care how many times you mount. It is just wrapper around `sftp` protocol, which brings the files and metadata to your mount. Not sure about the `encfs` stuff.

Comment: EncFS still uses AES iirc, not exactly "weak" unless a country's after your "definitely not adult files" ;-)

Comment: @Xen2050 I know but I read that it's kinda easy to break if you have multiple versions of the encrypted file which happens if my provider's automatic backup kicks in. But I don't really care. I just don't want anyone to have a look at my holiday pics and payslips.